# The type or namespace name 'Job' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: sitecore-api

I'm upgrading a project from Sitecore 9.1.1 to Sitecore 10.
After I changed all the DLLs from Sitecore version 9.1.1 to 10.0 and migrated the project from .Net 4.7.2 to 4.8 I had this problem with the Job, any Idea how can I solve it?

[image]

BTW, I tried to use these namespaces to solve the issue but nothing worked

```
using Sitecore.Jobs
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentExtraction.IFilter.Job
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **Sitecore.Jobs.Job** and **Sitecore.Jobs.JobOptions** classes have been removed in Sitecore 9.2. In their place you now have **BaseJob** and **BaseJobOptions** abstractions with **DefaultJob** and **DefaultJobOptions** concrete classes

In your case you can use **DefaultJobOptions**. You can see the constructor looks to be the same like on **JobObtions**.

```
public DefaultJobOptions(
      string jobName,
      string category,
      string siteName,
      object obj,
      string methodName)
      : this(jobName, category, siteName, obj, methodName, (object[]) null, false)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) jobName, nameof (jobName));
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) category, nameof (category));
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) siteName, nameof (siteName));
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull(obj, nameof (obj));
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) methodName, nameof (methodName));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Vlad, I just found BaseJob data type in Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseJob