# SPE is not working

Tags: powershell-extensions

When I run `PowerShell`, I am getting below error. What could be the reason?
Please assist.

SItecore 9.2 and SPE 5.0

[image]

Comment: Can you please mention which Sitecore and SPE versions you are using? Also, Please provide all the stack traces and error messages as text.

Comment: Does this help? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/27797/946

Comment: @RamanGupta - Sitecore 9.2 and SPE 5.0